# Adding two big numbers made as two arrays

Tags: java, arrays

So I have to make a method that add two big numbers (made as two arrays in which each digit is a different character). I've already made a code but it's not working properly. Could someone help me and look over it?

```
public BigNumber add(BigNumber number2){
    BigNumber x = null;
    char[] m = null;
    long y = 0;
    boolean tmpBool = false;
    boolean leftIsLonger = false;

    if (this.n.length >= number2.n.length){
        m = new char[this.n.length + 1];
        y = number2.n.length;
        leftIsLonger = true;
    }else{
        m = new char[this.n.length + 1];
        y = this.n.length;
    }

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < y; i++){
        char[] tmp1 = new char[1];
        this.number.getChars(i, i, tmp1, 1);
        int left = Character.getNumericValue(tmp1[0]);

    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < y; j++){
        char[] tmp2 = new char[1];
        this.number.getChars(i, i, tmp2, 1);
        int right = Character.getNumericValue(tmp2[0]);

        int z = left + right;

        if (tmpBool){
            z++;
            tmpBool = false;
        }

        if (z > 9){
            tmpBool = true;
            z = z%10;
        }

        m[i]= (char) z;
    }}

    for (int k = i; k < m.length - 1; k--){
        if (leftIsLonger){
            if (tmpBool){
                int c = Character.getNumericValue(this.n[k]);
                if (c > 9){
                    tmpBool = true;
                    c = c%10;
                    m[k] = (char) (c);
                }else{
                    tmpBool = false;
                    m[k] = (char) (c + 1);
                }
            }else
                m[k] = this.n[k];
        }else{
            if (tmpBool){
                int c = Character.getNumericValue(number2.n[k]);
                if (c > 9){
                    tmpBool = true;
                    c = c%10;
                    m[k] = (char) (c);
                }else{
                    tmpBool = false;
                    m[k] = (char) (c + 1);
                }
            }else
                m[k] = this.n[k];
        }
    }

    return x;
}
```

Comment: You need to explain why code not working? what is the out put you are getting?

Comment: Please explain elaborately what is wrong with your code. Imagining your loops and condition is quite difficult

Comment: For code review, there's [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) ... :)

Comment: It gives me 'null'. I don't know how to make it return the right result of the addition.

Comment: @Fildor I thought code review was for code "quality", and not for code correctness?

Comment: @Fabinout Hm, that's right. Was a little fast there, again.

Comment: @user3165933 Do you get an exception or just not the result you expected?

Comment: Erm, in the beginning you create `BigNumber x = null` and in the end you return it. But in between, I cannot seem to find any place where it is set? So the whole function "optimizes" to `return null;`

Comment: Any reasons you are not using java.math.BigInteger for this?

Answer (score 2):

In the beginning you create `BigNumber x = null` and in the end you return it. 
But in between, I cannot seem to find any place where it is set? 
So the whole function "optimizes" to

```
public BigNumber add(BigNumber number2){
    return null;
}
```

That is what you do and that is why it is returning null, always.